# Bash case statement

Tags: bash, shell, case

I'm trying to learn case as I was to write a fully functional script.

I'm starting off with the below

```
#!/bin/sh
case $@ in

    -h|--help)
            echo "You have selected Help"
            ;;
    -B|-b)
            echo "You have selected B"
            ;;
    -C|-c)
            echo "You have selected C"
            ;;
      *)
            echo "Valid Choices are A,B,C"
            exit 1
            ;;
esac
```

I want to use two of these options:

```
./getopts.sh -h -c
```

But i get this result
    Valid Choices are A,B,C

Please can you help out and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

I want to build a script that will do something if you enter one option but do multiple things if you enter multiple.

Also how would i parse $1 to this script as surley which ever option i enter first (-h) will be $1 ??

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `getopts` instead of `case`?

Comment: I'm open to any ideas as i haven't really used either. I need to learn this rather than having 1000's of nested if statements

Comment: @fedorqui Even with getopts, one still needs a loop (usually a `while` loop) and some kind of case analysis, and `case` is much better than `if ... elif ...` for that purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
    echo `basename $0`: ERROR: $* 1>&2
    echo usage: `basename $0` '[-a] [-b] [-c] 
        [file ...]' 1>&2
    exit 1
}


while :
do
    case "$1" in
    -a|-A) echo you picked A;;
    -b|-B) echo you picked B;;
    -c|-C) echo you picked C;;
    -*) usage "bad argument $1";;
    *) break;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: Okay, looking good. One furhter question if i wanted -a to do `whois $1` how would i make this work i want the usage to be something like `./script.sh -a example.com` or `./script.sh -a -b example.com` any ideas on that?

Answer (score 6):

Using `getopt` or `getopts` is the better solution. But to answer your immediate question, `$@` is *all* of your arguments, so `-h -c`, which doesn't match any of the single-argument patterns in your case statement. You would still need to iterate over your arguments like so

```
for arg in "$@"; do
    case $arg in
       ....
    esac
done
```

Comment: FWIW: `for arg in "$@"; do ...` is equivalent to `for arg; do ...`

Answer (score 0):

to parse the positional arguments like ... $1 , just use $1 in the case stmt and then at the end ... use shift to pust the 2nd arg to $1 and likewise .

also i would put the case stmt in a while loop or better a fxn so that i can run it twice for the two options or the number of options ..........

$# will let you know how many options/arguments were there .