# How to use case to identify a specific pattern in BASH script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to identify several folders in my script that run from 101-121. The script is written to look through one specific folder at a time.

The error I get is:

```
command not found
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Piece of my code that is not working.

```
for i in 1;                 
do
  case $i in    
    1)

    projectfolder= `ls -l| grep "1*"` ;; #trying to identify individual folders 101-121

  esac
done
```

does not localize the folders very well.

Comment: side-note: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs . Also please use https://www.shellcheck.net/ before posting syntax questions

Comment: So which line is the 25th line? You posted only 8 lines. Did you run your script via https://www.shellcheck.net/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16673570/608639). Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is the `total` symbol that your first error message is about? Did you run your script via https://www.shellcheck.net/?

Comment: I copied this straight from my script and ran it through my terminal, so line 25 is where the error is in m actual script. Also, I'll try to run the script in shellcheck.net

Comment: @hek2mgl - Why doesn't the site inform users about Shellcheck when using the Bash tag? Or better, run their code through Shellcheck for them? Why are we manually repeating it for nearly every question?

Comment: @jww tag wikis are there for informing users, and you can't expect administration to add special features for a certain tag

Comment: @jww That's a great idea! If you have the energy to bring that up on meta, cool!

Comment: (discussion started already :) )

Comment: wow, that's surprising. shellcheck doesn't find syntax errors any more?

Comment: Although `projectfolder= $(cmd with no output)` should certainly generate a warning, it's not a syntax error.  Just a really weird thing to do. (Setting a variable in the environment of an empty simple command which isn't executed.) . If an environment variable is set for a command that isn't run, does anyone hear it?

Comment: Shellcheck produces [7 findings](https://pastebin.com/TBtfwM6Q) for your code. You should fix them before continuing.

Answer (score 2):

```
projectfolder= `ls -l| grep "1*"`
```

is a terrible thing to do.  First, you probably intended to write `projectfolder=$(ls -l| grep "1*")` (using `$()` for readability, but the important detail is the lack of space after the `=`), but doing that is also a bad idea. Why not just do `for i in 1*; do ...`?

Comment: Additionally, `1*` matches everything; I think the intention was `'^1'` instead. But anyway, your glob is the way to go instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your project folders all follow the naming pattern you describe, you should use **brace expansion** to expand to the numbers `101..121` and then easily iterate over them:

```
for projectfolder in {101..121} ; do
  [ -d "$projectfolder" ] && echo "'${projectfolder}' exists and is a directory." 
done
```

Brace expansion does not check for any of the directories' existence, so to see which one are actually there, you would test each one using `[ -d`.

Search for `Brace Expansion` in the `bash(1)` manual page and type `help test` for more information